# iTunes media keys not working in Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: macbook-pro, itunes

My media keys had stopped working in iTunes on my Macbook Pro. They were working fine in VLC. I tried checking for the usual suspects:

- iTunes preferences
- Google Chrome Play music extension

Neither of them was the case for me.

I created a new user account on my Mac and the media keys worked fine on that one. So I tried copying the `com.apple.itunes` files from the Library of that account into the main account. This didn't help neither. What should I do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally, I ran the following 2 commands in my terminal:

```
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist
launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist
```

Worked like a charm!

Comment: It didn't work for me somehow, macOS Sierra v10.12.2 on Macbook Air. does this require a system restart?

Comment: this was already quite easy to find: https://superuser.com/a/827710/28411